# How many objects are created by the following code?

Tags: java, object

I had an exam where I should look at this code and answer the following question.

> ```
> Object a,b,c,d,e;
> e= new Object();
> b=a=e;
> e= new Object();
> ```
>
> How many objects are created by this code ?

The possible answers were these ones:

- 2
- 5
- 4
- Invalid code

It looks like 2 was the right answe, but I don't understand why – I see 5 objects (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) here, don't I?

Comment: Mark homework as such, and explain your answer and thought process **before** coming to ask.

Comment: Happy to help with homework, but -1 for asking without giving it a go first. You'll learn a great deal more if you see what your own answer is first.

Comment: This is not homework but, I am sure this is a question from upwork.com JAVA test because I ended up here, searching for the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two objects will be  instantiated

```
Object a,b,c,d,e; // only declares a to e as Object (at this time they are not initialized)
e= new Object(); // 1st e refers to a newly created object
b=a=e;           // b and a refer both to the same object as e
e= new Object(); // 2nd, this instantion and assignment does not 
                 // change a or b, a and b still refer to the 1st created  Object
```

Comment: Your third line comment is misleading. b and a both have the same value as e - they all refer to the same object. It's not like a and b are really related to e though; they happen to have the same value *at that point*. In particular, changing the value of e does *not* change the value of a or b.

Comment: No, it's still wrong - b and a *don't* refer to e. They refer to the same object that e refers to.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 calls to `new Object()`, so 2. Code looks valid.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is the keyword to "create" an object.  There are 2 `new` objects, so 2 objects are created.

Answer (score 1):

Two different objects.

The first is created on the first `e= new Object();` and then, the reference, is copied into `a` and `b`.
This means that `e,a,b` **points to the same object**

The second object is created on the second `e= new Object();`

So, you have:

```
a,b --> points to Object "one"
e --> point to Object "two"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two different objects will be created.

You can check this by looking at the results of `hashCode()` as well.

The first time when when `obj` is created, `b`, `a`, and `e` are pointing to that object.

The second time, when the new object is created with `e = new Object()`, `e` is now pointing to this object, while `b`,and `a` are still pointing to the old object.